# Using if statement in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I have some values like:

```
0.0016662256300037
0.0039870529599284
621.26166045405
-5.99733512656
-223.045
```

I don't to show if value is zero or equal to zero. I mean I don't want to show these two values 0.0016662256300037 and 0.0039870529599284 currently I am using:

```
if($pay_balance != '0' ){
    echo $pay_balance;
}
```

Comment: 0.0016662256300037 - weird value for `$pay_balance`, to say the least.

Comment: What' s the problem here? Are you sure that the numbers are strings? Other wise you should do this: `$pay_balance !== 0`

Comment: so many downvotes, and so many wrong answers. Sometimes SO confuses me. I think this is a valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the @undone comment

```
if(intval($pay_balance) !=0){
   echo $pay_balance;
}
```

[intval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

Comment: `intval` and `(int)` return different values if the variable is a string.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini you'r right, but in the question I didn't saw string and the op said is working...

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting

Comment: The documentation warns about using `(int)` on fractions. I changed my downvote to up. This is now the right answer :)

Comment: @MathewFoscarini thanks for the link, I'm learning some new thing to me from there

Answer (score 2):

Try using PHP number_format:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

```
number_format($pay_balance, 2);
```

This way numbers with low precision line 0.003 will become 0.00, but if you still want something like 0.1 to be shown it will (instead of just rounding off).

Note that this returns a string, you could cast it to a float from here to do a comparison with 0:

```
if ((float) number_format($pay_balance, 2) != 0) {
  echo $pay_balance;
}
```

Comment: Downvote with no comment...  This solution left options rather than just casting it to an int and comparing to 0.  OP might have wanted 0.9 to be displayed and this would have allowed it and still got rid of .001 for example.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ignore the decimal part of the number, you can convert the value to integer.

```
if ((int) $pay_balance != 0) {
  echo $pay_balance;
}
```